# Taking two HeaderParam in GET, a strange mistake for int @HeaderParam

Tags: java, angularjs, get, header, jersey

I post two Headers from a js file in a GET REST Call:

```js
allstaffworking: function(_getstaff){
            var currentToken = _GetToken();

            var Headers = {
                token: currentToken.tokenStaff,
            };
            
            var HeaderId = {
                idtoken: currentToken.idtokenStaff,
            };
            
            
            
            console.log("idtoken"+Headers);

            if (currentToken !== null) {
            $http({  
                        method : 'GET',  
                        headers: Headers, HeaderId,
                        url : REST_URL+'staff/working'
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {  
                        _getstaff(response)
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {  
                        console.log(response.statusText);  
                    });  
               }  else {
                console.log("NON SEI LOGGATO!!!");
            }
        },
```

The Headers are:

```
 var Headers = {
            token: currentToken.tokenStaff,
        };

        var HeaderId = {
            idtoken: currentToken.idtokenStaff,
        };
```

This is the java page called by REST_URL+'staff/working':

```html
public List<Staff> getStaff()  
 {  
  List<Staff> listOfStaff=sDao.getAll(Staff.class);
  return listOfStaff;  
 }  
    
    @GET  
    @Path("/working")  
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public List<Staff> getWStaff(@HeaderParam("token") String token, @HeaderParam("idtoken") int tokenid) 
 {  
   
    s = (Staff) sDao.getById(tokenid, Staff.class);
    st = (StaffType) sDao.getById(s.getStaffType().getIdstaffType(), StaffType.class);
   
    
    if (ex && st.getIdstaffType()==2){
     List<Staff> listOfWStaff=stfDao.getAllW();
     return listOfWStaff;  
    }
    else
     return null;
 }
```

taking the two Header with: `@HeaderParam("token") String token, @HeaderParam("idtoken") int tokenid`
The first Header Param works, the second doesn't works, look this debug's image
[image]

How you can see from the image, the idtoken's header value is `11`.
Therefore my java class should work taking this second @HeaderParman such int. But it doesn't work, error 500. I try to manually insert "11" , in this way:

```
s = (Staff) sDao.getById(11, Staff.class);
```

And in this way it works!! Then, the mistake is when I take the second @HeaderParam, I've also tried with take tokenid as String, an convert it using `Integer.parseint(tokenid)`
but it does not change.
I hope that somebody can help me

Answer (score 0):

$http config object's header property takes an object as param, as you are passing 2 objects its picking the first one. Ideally you should pass something like this:

```
$http({
    ...
    headers: {
        token: currentToken.tokenStaff,
        idtoken: currentToken.idtokenStaff
    }
    ...
});
```

Also I am curious as to why you are not getting error in line where you are providing Headers and HeaderId as comma separated.

Comment: Nothing.. " 403 (Forbidden)"

Comment: Can you please paste the network inspected snapshot of the request that is going.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/GYPCW
Look, 3 element in each header "currentToken = Object {idtokenStaff: 11, staffType: Object, tokenStaff: "88d08m8ve4n8i71k796vajkd01" not one